# Entity Framework 6 (one parent table has more than one child table with one to many relationship) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my API application, I'm using Entity Framework 6 and SQL Server as backend.

I have the following DB design and EF configuration.

DB relationship: (please refer added image)

[Db relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlYAZ.png)

```
Parent table -----one to many ---> child1               
Parent table -----one to many ---> child2
```

Domain in code:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {            
        Child1 = new List<Child1>();
        Child2 = new List<Child2>();            
    }

    // Navigation properties
    public ICollection< Child1> Childs1{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<Child2> Childs2{ get; set; }
}
```

EF configuration:

Child1:

```
HasOptional(t => t.Parent)
                .WithMany(t => t.Childs1)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t. ParentId);
```

Child2:

```
HasOptional(t => t.Parent)
                .WithMany(t => t.Childs2)
                .HasForeignKey(t => t. ParentId);
```

Let's say the child1 table as 8 records linked with the `parentId = '12345'`, and the child2 table as 8 records linked with `parentId = '12345'`

When I execute the following query it’s returning 8 * 8 = 64 records, instead of 8 + 8 = 16 records.

```
select * 
from Parent p
inner join Child1 c1 on c1.Parent = p.Id
inner join Child2 c2 on c2.Parent = p.Id
where p.Id = '12345'
```

Please help me, why this issue is happening and how to resolve it.

1. Should I change the DB design, if yes what would be the EF configuration for the same(how to implement navigation property)
2. With EF configuration modification can we resolve this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your second inner join is joining on the wrong table column:

```
inner join Child2 c2 on c1.Parent=p.Id
```

c1.Parent should be c2.Parent

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting the results in entity framework? 
The sql query result returns what is expected to return. the join operation returns all matches, so the first join will be 1*8, which will be 8 records, and the second will join the results from the first join with the second child table which will be 8*8 = 64 records. EF should be able to clean this up and you should get one object with the 2 collections of children, as you expect to get.

Comment: agreed, but I have executed the EF generated query for the same on DB server that returns again 64 records. is this behaviour reduce query performance?

Comment: Obviously, returning more records will impact performance. It shouldn't be noticeable for smaller result sets, but if you expect to return a lot of results, you could consider alternatives, like writing stored procedures and doing a lot more of the processing on the sql server side.